# Storing multiple sets of radio button values into object angularjs (without jQuery)

Tags: javascript, angularjs

In this slimmed down version of my controller and view, I am attempting to store the user selection of multiple sets of radio buttons, grouped in threes, within an object. I then will send the object within ajax call in order to store via SQL database. I have succeeded in doing this, however I had to use jQuery to do so. Any ideas on ways to do this within the angularjs framework, hence avoiding the jQuery usage? In case you’re wondering, the radio buttons represent present and absent, in order to keep attendance for a large list of students. Thank you!

```
<tr ng-repeat="s in rollCallList">
    <td align="left">{{s.Last_Name}}, {{s.First_Name}}</td>
    <td>
         <input name="{{s.dc_number}}" id="id1{{s.dc_number}}" type="radio" value="P" ng-checked="radiocheck" />P
                <input name="{{s.dc_number}}" id="id2{{s.dc_number}}" type="radio" value="A" />A
                <input name="{{s.dc_number}}" id="id3{{s.dc_number}}" type="radio" value="X" />X
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td colspan="2">
           <button class="btn" ng-show="SaveAttBtn" ng-click="SaveAtt(RollCallDate)">Save Attendance</button>
           <button class="btn" ng-show="DeleteAttBtn" ng-click="DeleteAtt(RollCallDate)">Delete Attendance</button>
    </td>
</tr>

$scope.SaveAtt = function (dt) {
        $scope.rollCallList.forEach(function (obj) {

            var dc = obj.dc_number;
            var attVal = $('input[name=' + dc + ']:checked').val();

            obj.status = attVal;
            obj.classDate = dt;

            console.log(obj);
        });
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<input name="dcNumber_{{s.dc_number}}" type="radio" ng-model="s.status" ng-value="'P'" />P
<input name="dcNumber_{{s.dc_number}}" type="radio" ng-model="s.status" ng-value="'A'" />A
<input name="dcNumber_{{s.dc_number}}" type="radio" ng-model="s.status" ng-value="'X'" />X
```

When looping through your items, `s.status` will have the selected ng-value. As for ng-checked, you should set the s.status to equal to the value you want to be auto selected. (P,A,X)

Comment: This is indeed the correct solution. Thanks! I should have known, as conceptually I've used similar solutions elsewhere. It's just that I'm still new to angular, so I occasionally have blurs in my programming vision. I have a question though: what is 'ng-value' directive for? I replaced it with the normal 'value' html property, and still got the same result. Being that both work correctly, what purpose does 'ng-value' have here? Thanks again

Comment: ng-value will allow expression, while value would just be a string. If you say wanted the value P,A,X to come from a variable inside of the ng-repeat or any other scope variable, you would use ng-value. so example ng-value="s.something" and the s.status would have the contents of s.something when its selected. By wraping it in single quotes, we forced it be a literally string expression. Just a preference I chose ng-value.